# Passing output of execvpe into a string in C

Tags: c, string, client-server, exec

I have to create a iterative server that receives directory arguments from a client. It then has to run `ls -l` on each argument and write that data back to the client.

I have all my arguments from the client set up to run `execvpe()` on the server, but I need to figure out how to pass the output of `execvpe()` into a string, `char buf[BUFSIZ]`. I then need to write that string to the client using `write(new_socket, buf, BUFSIZ);`.

I also would like to have the output not appear on the server's side. Since right now, `ls -l (clients arguments)` (from the client side) outputs to my server.

Is there some way to do this?

Comment: There's an excellent example at https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~pxk/416/notes/c-tutorials/pipe.html. I don't want to copy and paste that code here.

Comment: Use a pipe so what the execvpe'd program writes on standard output is readable by the the other program.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So I would do the pipe in my `server` file, and pipe it to the stdout of the client program? How would I end up doing this :o

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So I sort of solved the problem. I'm doing `dup2(new_socket, 0); dup2(new_socket, 1); dup2(new_socket, 2);` and then calling `execvpe()`. This does end up redirecting the output, but for whatever reason it only redirects a little bit of output and then stops before it finishes.

Comment: Not sure about the `dup2(new_socket, 0)`; if something is reading standard input, it could get some of the data sent to standard output and/or standard error.  But the general idea (use a socket instead of a pipe) is OK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I removed that and I still end up with the same results. There shouldn't be anything being read from stdin on either side, since everything is just command line arguments then it exits. My only guess is since in my client it does `read(sockfd, buf, BUFSIZ)` it just can't hold all the information? Is there a way to get past that?

Comment: Maybe you need to call `read()` multiple times?  I'm not clear what `new_socket` is since you've not shown any code at all.  It is hard to know if that's the socket connecting the server to the client, or is intended to be a socket connecting the server to its child (the one that will execute `ls -l` for you). This is why there's a frequent mantra "show us the code", and a request for an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)). Our problem as answerers is that there are endless ways to get it wrong and only a few to get it right.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler You're completely right, I'm sorry about not posting code, I have some pretty weird restrictions for the assignment so it's super hard to read. Either way your suggestion fixed it for me, I just did this in my client (if anyone else reads this): `size_t check; while((check = read(sockfd,buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0) { write(1,buf,check); }`

Answer (score 0):

I sort of solved the problem. I'm doing `dup2(new_socket, 0); dup2(new_socket, 1); dup2(new_socket, 2);` and then calling `execvpe()`.
I just did this in my client (if anyone else reads this):

```
size_t check; while((check = read(sockfd,buf, BUFSIZ)) > 0) { write(1,buf,check); }
```

–  Alex